# Javascript to replace innerText and not if its an attribute

Tags: javascript

How to use Javascript to selectively replace the word called Rindan in he below text ,
but not if its in some attribute like img alt=="Rindan"
I want to replace the word Rindans which is an inner text and not if it is in attribute .

```
`"<a href="http://edition.cnn.com/video/?hpt=hp_t1#/video/bestoftv/2012/02/28/ac-marie-rindan-family-syria.cnn">Rindan's family on her legacy</a> &nbsp;<a href="http://edition.cnn.com/video/?hpt=hp_t1#/video/bestoftv/2012/02/28/ac-marie-Rindan-family-syria.cnn" target=""><img alt="Rindan's family on her legacy" border="0" class="cnnVideoIcon" height="10" src="http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/icons/video_icon.gif" width="16" /></a>`"
```

Comment: I need to use JS to parse a big HTML content and replace innerHtml's with some other data ..but if it is in attribute it should remain untouched .Further I will not be replacing with another name , but with a <span class="spellcheck_error">word</span> . I am looking for an approach like htmlcontent = some string . Use htmlparser on this and replace only the textual contens .

Comment: Input - HTML CONTENT as a text ------>  Output replace spellcheck error words within a span class -----> ( Ofcourse I already have an array of words with erros ] . If the word is in some attribute just ignore it and replace only if its a text .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function parameter in `replace` function of string

```
your_string = your_string.replace(<regexp>,  
     function(matched, index){
        // check matched 
        return replacement;
     }); 
});
```

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: This is a helpful thing actually . Thanks . You actually saw my problem  .

Answer (score 1):

Give the id to a block, get the innerHTML, and use the replace string function:

```
var get=document.getElementById('test');
var str=get.innerHTML;
document.write(str.replace("Rindan's","TestNAme"));
```

set this back to innerHTML

see live demo on 
http://jsfiddle.net/kunalvashist/CeeDU/

Comment: <a> tag is an example , I might have many tags .Consider the sources as a a big HTML document . I need to parse and replace only the inner HTML contents and not touch the other things .

Answer (score 0):

this is to replace the text and not the attributes:

```
var aa = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(i=0;i<=aa.length;i++)
{
aa[i].innerText = aa[i].innerText.replace("Rindan","anyone");
}
​
```

Comment: DOM methods will not help me much I think . I need a combination of HTML parsing and regex .

Comment: No, you don't. Regex is unnecessary, unless you've got more words, or instances of the same word perhaps, that you need to change. [Don't parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/82548), it's not pretty. Or safe.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop all children elements of the body tag and do a replace on the innerhtml.

```
var body_children = document.body.children;
for(var i = 0; i < body_children.length; i++){
   var str = body_children[i].innerHTML
   body_children[i].innerHTML = str.replace("this","with this");
}
```

Comment: `int i`, do you mean `var i`?